# How to plot two different ProbabilityScalePlot on the same graph?

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics

```
spCnts1 = {12.5, 17.8, 19.9, 21.40, 25.6, 28.4, 29.5, 30.2, 35.1, 
40.1, 46.4, 47.5, 48.3, 50.2, 53.2, 55.9, 56.3, 57.51, 60.3, 62.3, 
65.4, 66.4, 68.60, 71.2};

ab = ProbabilityScalePlot[spCnts1, "LogNormal", ImageSize -> Medium, 
PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All]

bc = ProbabilityScalePlot[spCnts1, "Weibull", ImageSize -> Medium, 
PlotRange -> All]

Show[bc, ab]
```

I am not able to get the required scale for both of the plots.

Can both plots be combine together properly, on a same plot?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "required scale"? Have you tried `Show[bc, ab, PlotRange -> All]`, and if so, what about that looks wrong to you?

Answer (score 1):

To find `PlotRange` for each plot, run

```
Options[ab, PlotRange]
Options[bc, PlotRange]
```

Then adjust your code as follows:

```
spCnts1 = {12.5, 17.8, 19.9, 21.40, 25.6, 28.4, 29.5, 30.2, 35.1, 
   40.1, 46.4, 47.5, 48.3, 50.2, 53.2, 55.9, 56.3, 57.51, 60.3, 62.3, 
   65.4, 66.4, 68.60, 71.2};

ab = ProbabilityScalePlot[spCnts1, "LogNormal", ImageSize -> Medium, 
   PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> {{0, 72}, {-4, 3}}];
bc = ProbabilityScalePlot[spCnts1, "Weibull", ImageSize -> Medium, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 72}, {-4, 3}}];
Show[bc, ab]
```

This will generate:

[image]